# send images on whatsapp web with javascript DOM

Tags: google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

How do I send images on whatsapp web, through javascript, I already have the script that sends the message, but I would like to increase this image function

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong you want to trigger send button via dom.
Short answer is you will have to get the button first then hit click like this:-

```
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Send"]').click()
```

screenshot:- https://prnt.sc/LdKzLkVkM5YY